# Download image using Axios in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm trying to download an image using a GET request in Axios, and then download this to the users PC.  I need to use Axios as the get request has an Authorization header.

Below I have my function to download the image and store it as a blob:

```
return axios({
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}` },
  url: `https://example.com/api/${url}`,
  responseType: 'blob'
})
.then(response => {
  if (response) {
    const file = new Blob([response.data], {type:'image/png'})
    return file
  }
  return Promise.reject('An unknown error occurred');
});
```

I then user FileSaver to save this:

```
  const image = await userService.downloadImage(slug, this.props.token);
  FileSaver.saveAs(image, "image.png")
```

What I am getting though is an error when downloading the file saying

> "Failed - Network Error"

If I look in the developer option of Chrome,  I can see the GET request to the API, and in the preview tab, I can see the image.

Any suggestions as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This means axios works fine, however, file-saver does not do the Download.

Looking into [readme of file-saver repo](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js#supported-browsers), you could see the supported browsers:

[image]

Thus, try to upgrade the current browser or test with another browser.
Also, make sure the size of the image does not exceed sizes mentioned in the  matrix above.

You can check the size by adding `console.log(file.size)`

```
.then(response => {
  if (response) {
    const file = new Blob([response.data], {type:'image/png'})
    console.log(file.size) // !!! this line
    return file
  }
```

Comment: I'm using the latest version of Chrome to test, and the file size is 275088